# How to convert Linux 32-bit gcc inline assembly to 64-bit code?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm attempting to convert [RR0D Rasta Ring 0 Debugger](http://rr0d.droids-corp.org/) from 32-bit mode to 64-bit mode (long mode) in Linux, using gcc. I'm familiar with x86 32-bit assembly (in MS-DOS environment) but I'm a beginner in x86 64-bit assembly and in Linux assembly programming in general.

This project is for production use (I need a working non-source debugger), but I also attempt to learn how to do the 32-bit to 64-bit conversion. If possible, I attempt to find a universal way to do 32-bit to 64-bit conversion that could be done on any 32-bit program using regular expressions (so that it can be automatized). I'm aware that no general solution exists (64-bit code may take more space than 32-bit code etc. and consume more stack etc.), but even in that case automatically converted code would serve as a starting point.

The idea would be to keep 8-bit and 16-bit operands as is, and replace 32-bit operands with 64-bit operands. This approach will naturally fail if `pushw %ax; pushw %bx; popl %ecx` is replaced with `pushw %ax; pushw %bx; popq %rcx`, but well-behaved programs usually don't `push` two 16-bit operands and then `pop` one 32-bit operand, or do they?.

These are the conversions so far:

**Edit:** Fix: `pusha` / `pushad` **can** be replaced with consecutive `push`'es, because `pusha` / `pushad` commands push the value of `sp` / `esp` *before* the actual push of `sp`, and `push sp` works the same way in 286+, but differently in 8088/8086 [The Assembly Language database](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~forest/HtmlFolder/AC/NG/ng142bb.html). This difference not an issue here (for 386+ code). `pusha` and `pushad` can thus be replaced with consecutive `push` commands.

An alternative is similar as in [OpenSolaris' `privregs.h` code](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/intel/amd64/sys/privregs.h).

**Edit:** Fix: use 64-bit memory addressing for all commands.

1. `pusha` -> `push %ax; push %cx; push %dx; push %bx; push %sp; push %bp; push %si; push %di`.

   **Edit:** Fix: A valid alternative (using `lea`), note that x86 processors are little-endian: `pusha` -> `movq %rax, -8(%rsp); lea -8(%rsp), %rax; mov %ax, -10(%rsp); movq -8(%rsp), %rax; movw %cx, -4(%rsp); movw %dx, -6(%rsp); movw %bx, -8(%rsp); movw %bp, -12(%rsp); movw %si, -14(%rsp); movw %di, -16(%rsp); lea -16(%rsp), %rsp`.
2. `pushad` -> `push %rax; push %rcx; push %rdx; push %rbx; push %rsp; push %rbp; push %rsi; push %rdi`.

   **Edit**: Fix: A valid alternative (using `lea`): `pushad` -> `movq %rax, -8(%rsp); movq %rcx, -16(%rsp); movq %rdx, -24(%rsp); movq %rbx, -32(%rsp); lea -32(%rsp), %rax; movq %rax, -40(%rsp); movq -8(%rsp), %rax; movq %rbp, -48(%rsp); movq %rsi, -56(%rsp); movq %rdi, -64(%rsp); lea -64(%rsp), %rsp`.

   **Edit:** Fix: `popa` and `popad` pop the value of `sp` / `esp` but discard it ([Intel instruction set - popa/popad](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/popa_popad.html)) . Let's `pop` it into `bx` / `rbx`.
3. `popa` -> `popw %di; popw %si; popw %bp; popw %bx; popw %bx; popw %dx; popw %cx; popw %ax`.
4. `popad` -> `popq %rdi; popq %rsi; popq %rbp; popq %rbx; popq %rbx; popq %rdx; popq %rcx; popq %rax`.
5. `pushfd` -> `pushfq`.
6. `popfd` -> `popfq`.
7. **Edit:** `push` of segment registers, eg. `pushw %ds` -> `pushw %ax; pushw %ax; movw %ds, %ax; movw %ax, 2(%rsp); popw %ax`.
8. **Edit:** `pop` of segment registers, eg. `popw %ds` -> `pushw %ax; movw 2(%rsp), %ax; movw %ax, %ds; popw %ax`.
9. **Edit:** `inc %reg16` -> `add $1, %reg16`, eg. `inc %ax` -> `add $1, %ax`.
10. **Edit:** `dec %reg16` -> `sub $1, %reg16`, eg. `dec %ax` -> `sub $1, %ax`.
11. **Edit:** `inc %reg32` -> `add $1, %reg64`, eg. `inc %eax` -> `add $1, %rax`.
12. **Edit:** `dec %reg32` -> `sub $1, %reg64`, eg. `dec %eax` -> `sub $1, %rax`.
13. **Edit:** `aaa` -> ?
14. **Edit:** `aad` -> ?
15. **Edit:** `aam` -> ?
16. **Edit:** `aas` -> ?
17. **Edit:** `arpl` -> ?
18. **Edit:** `bound` -> ?
19. **Edit:** `daa` -> ?
20. **Edit:** `das` -> ?
21. **Edit:** `lahf` -> ?
22. **Edit:** `sahf` -> ?
23. **Edit** Fix: any command with direct operand that does not fit in 32-bit operand size in 64-bit mode, eg. `pushl $0xDEADBEEF` -> `pushq %rax; pushq %rax; movq $0xDEADBEEF, %rax; movq %rax, 8(%rsp); popq %rax`.
24. `ret` with immediate operand: I think in this case the source code must be backtraced to see the sizes of last `push`ed operands, and act accordingly, eg. `pushl %eax; ret 4` -> `pushq %rax; ret 8`.
25. **Edit:**: syscalls: `int $0x80` -> `pushq %rdi; movq %rbp, %r9; movq %rdi, %r8; movq %rbx, %rdi; xchgq %rcx, %rsi; -- replace %rax value using a substitution list --; syscall; popq %rdi; xchgq %rcx, %rsi` (note: 32-bit syscalls may have more than 6 parameters, 6 in registers and the rest in stack, 64-bit syscalls may never have more than 6 parameters).

**Edit:** What else should be taken into account? What other conversions would be needed to convert 32-bit code to 64-bit code (to be run in long mode) ?

Comment: did you see `llvm` ? may it will be usefull for your needs. http://llvm.org/

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I haven't tried `llvm`, I'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that'll be sufficient. There are deeper differences between x86 and x86_64 than just the size of registers.

Comment: Indeed -- standard calling convention is very different.

Comment: @ephemient I edited my question and added replacement `syscall` code for `int $0x80`.

Comment: Use a decompiler on your assembly to obtain C, then compile that C using gcc -m64.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ha ha ha no. Not only does that technique not work reliably even for simple userland code, but the code that nrz is working with here is an insanely low-level debugger, so a lot of what it's doing is probably not even *representable* in C. Performing a "blind idiot translation" like that will definitely not work.

Comment: @duskwuff of course, I was just kidding... :)

Comment: This is a good question, I don't know why they closed it.