# Errors in compiling Linux kernel module: "CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support" and unwanted "n" characters

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, compiler-warnings

I am trying to get [Rasta Ring0 Debugger](http://rr0d.droids-corp.org/) version 0.3 compiled in my x86-64 Linux, it's a Linux kernel module. I have replaced 32-bit inline assembly with 64-bit assembly as explained in my question [How to convert Linux 32-bit gcc inline assembly to 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897116/how-to-convert-linux-32-bit-gcc-inline-assembly-to-64-bit-code) , by using Vim regular expressions, and gcc gives no syntax errors. But I get several other errors.

My computer is a Lenovo W520 laptop with Intel Core i7-2760QM and I'm using Debian GNU/Linux Wheezy.

These are first lines of the output of `$ make >make_output.txt 2>&1`

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-3.5.4'
/usr/src/linux-3.5.4/arch/x86/Makefile:96: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/module_nux.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c: In function ‘insert_bp’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:66:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

First, `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support`. But in my custom kernel `.config` it's clear that it's a 64-bit system:

```
#
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# Linux/x86_64 3.5.4 Kernel Configuration
#
CONFIG_64BIT=y
# CONFIG_X86_32 is not set
CONFIG_X86_64=y
CONFIG_X86=y
CONFIG_INSTRUCTION_DECODER=y
CONFIG_OUTPUT_FORMAT="elf64-x86-64"
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig"
```

Second, there is this row in `$ make >make_output.txt 2>&1` output:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
```

Obviously there is no such program as `nobjdump`, it should be `objdump`. Where might this `n` come from? This same error is present later also with `ld`, in the form of `nld`. Any ideas where this error might originate and it could be solved?

The `Makefile` is the following:

```
# EXTRA_CFLAGS +=  -O2 -Wall -DLINUX_26
EXTRA_CFLAGS +=  -O2 -Wall -DLINUX_26 -m64

OBJ          := module_nux.o breakpoint.o buffering.o command.o disasmbak.o idt.o 
OBJ          += keyboard.o page.o video.o utils.o import_symb.o core_rr0d.o pci.o
MODULE       := rr0d.o 

obj-m        := $(MODULE)
rr0d-objs    := $(OBJ)

default:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules

clean:
    rm -f  *.o .*.o.cmd .*.ko.cmd *.mod.c  *~ 
    rm -rf .tmp_versions

mrproper:
    make clean
    rm -f *.ko
```

In `Makefile` I added `-m64` to `EXTRA_FLAGS` but it didn't change the `make` output.

In the end of output (entire output below) there are three more errors of the same type as the one above:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found

/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found

/bin/sh: 1: nld: not found
```

Clearly there are 3 `n` letters that shouldn't be there. Probably this is not related to Rasta Ring0 Debugger, because I got identical error also when trying to compile ['parrot' sample device driver for Linux 2.6 and 3.0](http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/08/writing-linux-device-driver-for-kernels.html).

So, any ideas how to solve these compiling errors? Googling around for days hasn't helped in this and I'm totally out of ideas.

This is the entire `$ make >make_output.txt 2>&1` output (including the 8 lines already presented above):

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-3.5.4'
/usr/src/linux-3.5.4/arch/x86/Makefile:96: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/module_nux.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c: In function ‘insert_bp’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:66:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:74:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:80:33: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:81:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c: In function ‘is_breakpoint’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:127:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c: In function ‘parse_inst’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:310:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:312:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c: In function ‘is_hw_breakpoint’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/breakpoint.c:600:40: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/buffering.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/command.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/disasmbak.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/idt.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/idt.c: In function ‘translate_logic_to_linear’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/idt.c:92:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/idt.c: In function ‘visualise_idt’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/idt.c:157:1: warning: the frame size of 2064 bytes is larger than 2048 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c: In function ‘back_disasm’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:500:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:511:27: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c: In function ‘handle_scancode’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:784:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:839:55: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:1230:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:1245:22: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/keyboard.c:1250:43: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c: In function ‘basetp’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:68:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c: In function ‘get_page_info’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:190:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:193:23: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c: In function ‘write_save_dirty’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:355:33: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:359:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c: In function ‘poked1’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:405:49: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:434:33: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:447:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/page.c:472:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/video.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/utils.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/import_symb.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.o
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘printf_disasm’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:314:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:318:53: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:319:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:344:12: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:358:44: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:393:50: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:417:11: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘dump_data’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:457:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:459:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:464:53: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:465:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘_kbdhandle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:817:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:824:45: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:841:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘kbdhandle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:845:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘step_by_step’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1041:44: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1063:49: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1181:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int0_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1185:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1366:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int1_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1370:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘_int3_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1430:30: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1495:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int3_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1499:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1540:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int6_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1544:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1586:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int13_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1589:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘_int14_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1605:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1606:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1648:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int14_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1651:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘_int128_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1664:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1665:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: At top level:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1687:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘int128_handle’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1691:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘init_rr0d’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1791:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1794:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1846:18: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1848:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1849:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1850:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1851:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1852:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1853:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1854:20: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1869:49: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘cleanup_rr0d’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1938:36: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/pci.o
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found
  LD [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.o
/bin/sh: 1: nld: not found
make[2]: *** [/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-3.5.4'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have [CONFIG_X86_X32](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/X86_X32.html)=y somewhere in your .config? It looks like you have [x32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) enabled and your toolchain doesn't support it.

Comment: @Banthar You're right. I confunded `CONFIG_X86_32` with `CONFIG_X86_X32`. Now recompiling the kernel and then a new attempt in compiling RR0D.

Comment: @Banthar Thanks, that solved the problem with `CONFIG_X86_X32`. But there's still the error caused by missing `nobjdump` and `nld`.

Comment: Problem with `nobjdump` and `nld` solved: `# cd /usr/bin; ln -s objdump nobjdump; ln -s ld nld` ... But still don't know the reason for that problem. Now `# insmod ./rr0d.o` prints: `Error: could not insert module ./rr0d.o: Invalid module format`. Have module formats changed since Linux 2.6?

Comment: @Banthar If you make a answer of your comment, I'll accept it. Actually, these fixes solved also the problem in compiling ['parrot' sample device driver for Linux 2.6 and 3.0](http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/08/writing-linux-device-driver-for-kernels.html), and both `insmod ./parrot_driver.ko` and `rmmod parrot_driver` work, and the module functionality too. So now I have a working kernel module, and I can begin learning Linux kernel programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself after solving these two problems, the first as indicated by Banthar, and the second by myself.

The first issue is that `CONFIG_X86_32` and `CONFIG_X86_X32` are two different variables. `CONFIG_X86_X32` (x32 ABI for 64-bit mode) must be set to `N` to solve the problem related with `binutils` support.

The other problem is with `nobjdump` and `nld`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nobjdump: not found

/bin/sh: 1: nld: not found
```

This can be fixed easily with symlinks:

```
$ su
# cd /usr/bin
# ln -s objdump nobjdump
# ln -s ld nld
```

Answer (score 5):

install binutils and try to remove the spaces b/w the path of driver. Check this out for complete details:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/367838/compiling-error-while-installing-realtek-rtl8111e-in-64-bit-13-10-config-x86-x

Answer (score 5):

This warning appears if `binutils` check in
`/usr/src/linux-headers-*-common/arch/x86/Makefile`
failed:

```
ifdef CONFIG_X86_X32
    x32_ld_ok := $(call try-run,\
            /bin/echo -e '1: .quad 1b' | \
            $(CC) $(KBUILD_AFLAGS) -c -x assembler -o "$$TMP" - && \
            $(OBJCOPY) -O elf32-x86-64 "$$TMP" "$$TMPO" && \
            $(LD) -m elf32_x86_64 "$$TMPO" -o "$$TMP",y,n)
        ifeq ($(x32_ld_ok),y)
                CONFIG_X86_X32_ABI := y
                KBUILD_AFLAGS += -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI
                KBUILD_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI
        else
                $(warning CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support)
        endif
endif
```

It failed if `binutils` assembly compilation isn't successfull.
Command above can be checked manually (executables and flags may differ):

```
CC=gcc-6
KBUILD_AFLAGS="-D__ASSEMBLY__  -m64"
OBJCOPY=objcopy
LD=ld
TMP=/tmp/dummytmp.tmp
TMPO=/tmp/dummyo.o

/bin/echo -e '1: .quad 1b' | \
$CC $KBUILD_AFLAGS -c -x assembler -o "$TMP" - && \
$OBJCOPY -O elf32-x86-64 "$TMP" "$TMPO" && \
$LD -m elf32_x86_64 "$TMPO" -o "$TMP"
```

Debian (and probably Ubuntu) users can check system integrity:

```
debsums -s
```

And reinstall broken packages:

```
apt-get install --reinstall <space separated packages>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about `nobjdump: not found`, but it's possible to get `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support` in some cases if the kernel source directory belongs to `root` and you're running as an unprivileged user. Try `sudo make`.

Another common cause of `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support` is spaces in the compilation directory, but that's clearly not an issue in your case.