# CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement a custom system call in Ubuntu 20.04.

One of the steps is this command

```
root@well:/usr/src/linux-5.16.15# sudo make modules_install install
```

But it gives this error:

```
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
ln: target '/source' is not a directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1477: __modinst_pre] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:350: __build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

What should I do to resolve it?

I've been at this for days and any help would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors in compiling Linux kernel module: "CONFIG\_X86\_X32 enabled but no binutils support" and unwanted "n" characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501124/errors-in-compiling-linux-kernel-module-config-x86-x32-enabled-but-no-binutils)

Comment: No. There are no spaces between the path of my driver and I don't understand the first reply...

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of `CONFIG_X86_X32` option:

> you will need a recent binutils (2.22 or later) with elf32_x86_x64 support enabled to compile a kernel with this option set.

This definition can be found at `arch/x86/Kconfig` file in kernel source code (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.15/source/arch/x86/Kconfig#L2836).
So in order to solve this problem, you can either disable this option or select a distro which supports high version binutils to compile the kernel.