# Error: could not insert module. Unknown symbol in module

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to port [RR0D Rasta Ring0 Debugger](http://rr0d.droids-corp.org/) from 32-bit Linux to 64-bit Linux. I have converted 32-bit gcc inline assembly to 64-bit using vim regex as mentioned in my question: [How to convert Linux 32-bit gcc inline assembly to 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897116/how-to-convert-linux-32-bit-gcc-inline-assembly-to-64-bit-code)

I'm using gcc with `-m64` flag. The target environment is Linux x86-64, custom kernel version 3.5.5.

The `Makefile` is the following:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS +=  -O2 -Wall -DLINUX_26 -m64

OBJ          := module_nux.o breakpoint.o buffering.o command.o disasmbak.o idt.o 
OBJ          += keyboard.o page.o video.o utils.o import_symb.o core_rr0d.o pci.o
MODULE       := rr0d.o 

obj-m        := $(MODULE)
rr0d-objs    := $(OBJ)

default:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules

clean:
    rm -f  *.o .*.o.cmd .*.ko.cmd *.mod.c  *~ 
    rm -rf .tmp_versions

mrproper:
    make clean
    rm -f *.ko
```

`make` gives a lot of warnings like `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]` and `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]`, but these are probably irrelevant to the topic.

The last rows of the output of `make` are probably the important ones:

```
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c: In function ‘cleanup_rr0d’:
/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/core_rr0d.c:1938:36: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  CC [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/pci.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "RING_HOOO_SEGMENT" [/home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/code/rr0d/0.3/rr0d.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/code/kernel/linux-3.5.5'
```

So, `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` is undefined.

When I try to `insmod` the module with `insmod ./rr0d.ko` as root, I get:

```
Error: could not insert module ./rr0d.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Checking with `dmesg | tail -n 1` gives the following output:

```
[15975.412346] rr0d: Unknown symbol RING_HOOO_SEGMENT (err 0)
```

So, the unknown symbol definitively is `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT`.

`RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` is a constant created with `#define` in `vars.h`, that is included in several `.c` files with `#include "vars.h"`.

The essential `#ifdef` block of `vars.h` with `#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` is this one:

```
#ifdef LINUX_26

#define fake_naked

#if defined(__GNUC__)
// the line below is the important one.
#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT "$0x7b"
//#define       RING_HOOO_SEGMENT "$0x60"
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT 0x7b
#endif

#else /* LINUX_24 */

#define fake_naked _asm_("\t" \
                     "add $0x08, %esp\n\t" \
                     "popl %ebp\n" \
);

#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT "$0x18"
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT 0x18
#endif

#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT_VALUE 0x18

#endif /* LINUX_26 */
```

Obviously if `#define RING_HOOO_SEGMENT "$0x7b"` (in `#if defined(__GNUC__)` inside `#ifdef LINUX_26`) is commented out, the code won't compile, so it's clear that `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` gets defined.

Grepping for `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` gives the following matches:

```
$ grep 'RING_HOOO_SEGMENT' *.c *.o *.ko

core_rr0d.c:    "movq RING_HOOO_SEGMENT, %rax\n\t"\
core_rr0d.c:  __asm{    movq RING_HOOO_SEGMENT, %rax}\
Binary file rr0d.ko matches
```

Both `core_rr0d.c` rows are inline assembly. `core_rr0d.c` contains `#include "vars.h"` so that should be fine.

Also the binary module `rr0d.ko` matches, so it contains the string `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` (in some form), even if `insmod ./rr0d.ko` fails with `Error: could not insert module ./rr0d.ko: Unknown symbol in module`.

Any ideas what might the reason for this problem and how to proceed to be able to `insmod` the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
core_rr0d.c:    "movq RING_HOOO_SEGMENT, %rax\n\t"\
```

Here RING_HOOO_SEGMENT is in a string (probably part of an inline assembler block). As such, the preprocessor will not substitute `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT`, and it gets passed as-is to the assembler, where the definition of `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` is not available.

Fortunately, `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` is itself defined as the string `"$0x7b"`, so we can use compile-time string concatenation:

```
"movq " RING_HOOO_SEGMENT ", %rax\n\t"\
```

The preprocessor will substitute `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` for `"$0x7b"`, then GCC will concatenate these strings before passing it down to the assembler.

Comment: Actually, both inline assembly rows are inside `#define` blocks. `"movq RING_HOOO_SEGMENT, %rax\n\t"\ ` is in a block defined this way: `#define HOOK_INT_HEADER_ASM(old_hooker)\ _asm_("\t"\ "pushq %rax\n\t"\ ` ... The other row is the same, for Microsoft C. However, as the row is inside a `#define` block and I don't know a method how to substitute `RING_HOOO_SEGMENT` inside a `#define` block, I decided to hardcode (and comment) it, for now. The module now loads but crashes Linux with `BUG: Unable to handle [xxxx.yyyyyy] kernel paging request at 00000000ffffd000`. But that's a different issue.

Comment: @nrz, You can still do what I said, even in a define block. It will get substituted multiple times until there are no macros left in the body.

Comment: You're right. I probably had some typo that caused the compilation to fail with `"movq " RING_HOOO_SEGMENT ", %rax\n\t"\ ` but I got it fixed and now it compiles.