# Using x86 materials to learn assembly on a 64 bit OS?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, abi

I am teaching myself/reading up about assembly. Most of the books on assembly refer to x86- all the register names in the code begin with "e" and not "r" (as they would in x86-64). However, I use 64-bit Linux and I was wondering if these books have any value because they are not referring to x86-64.

So in short- is it really worth me using these resources to learn x86-64. Or reworded differently, besides the difference in register naming convention- are there any other differences between the two which could make learning from x86 materials difficult?

Comment: The calling convention will be different, the other differences are really insignificant.

Comment: Besides the calling convention, one thing to remember is that using 32-bit register as a destination register always zeroes the top 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register. There are some other issues too. Not all 32-bit instructions (even relatively common ones) are valid 64-bit instructions, see my (closed) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897116/how-to-convert-linux-32-bit-gcc-inline-assembly-to-64-bit-code .

Answer (score 4):

64 bit Linux allows running 32bit applications, so you still can create 32 bit applications on your computer. This way, the books and example 32 bit code are fully useful.

The only single problem you might have is if the assembly application dynamically link to some 32 bit shared library. In order to fix this you should install 32 bit compatibility layer.

The assembly programs that use only Linux system calls works fine without this layer, which is actually set of shared libraries compiled for 32 bit.

BTW, in my opinion, writing 32 bit code is still better if you want your programs to be useful for more people. There are still many 32 bit computers around and they will not disappear soon.

Comment: You should also be aware that 64-bit assembler is more difficult to learn due to more complex calling conventions (not stack-based, special stack pointer alignment, ...). So writing 32-bit is definitely better for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a bit easier to learn assembly on 32bit since the calling conventions and stack management are simpler.

On 64bit you need to worry about ABI. Not only that but the conventions are not the same for every OSes. For instance, the ABI rules on Mac OS X are different than those on Windows (the registers are not the same and on Windows it only uses 4 registers).

You can compile your assembly code using -arch i386 with the assembler (as). With clang or gcc you can use -m32 (at least on Mac OS X, since I haven't used it on Linux proper). You won't be able to link modules that have different bitness (32bit vs 64bit).

Once you're ready to switch or compile your program for 64bit you will have to make sure that when you handle the stack you need to push 64bit words instead of 32bit ones but that kinda goes with saying.