# Differences of x86 and x86-64 machine code

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, jit, machine-code

So, I've got a program which generates JIT x86 machine code and executes it directly and I want it to support x86-64/AMD64/x64 as well. The obvious differences are:

- New registers (`rax`, `r8`...) and pointer width (pointers need to use 64bit regs)
- Default C calling convention (arguments on stack vs. registers)
- Some new mnemonics (`pushq` to push 64bit)

Are there any differences in the binary instructions as well or should it be (roughly) sufficient to use `pushq` and 64bit registers when appropriate and the code will just work?

Code example:

```
static inline void emit_call(uint32_t target) {
    emit_byte(0xE8);
    emit_dword(target - ((uint32_t)out + 4));
}
```

This would still work if I use `uintptr_t` instead of `uint32_t` I assume,
but loading an immediate into a 64bit register `rax` is different from loading it into the lower 32bit alias:

```
static void emit_mov_x86reg_immediate(int x86reg, int imm) {
    emit_byte(0xB8 | x86reg);
    emit_dword(imm);
}
```

Are there any other differences?

The code I'm working on is accessible [here](https://github.com/nspire-emus/firebird/blob/master/core/translate_x86.c), if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: There are quite a lot of differences. Some are listed in my (closed) SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897116/how-to-convert-linux-32-bit-gcc-inline-assembly-to-64-bit-code .

Comment: `push` is still the old instruction, no new mnemonics, just a new AT&T suffix, or just use Intel syntax where no suffix is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually no difference between the old 32bit push and the new 64bit push, that's one of the few instructions that are *implicitly* 64bit.

Relative branches and calls still use 32bit offsets.

Some actual differences are:

- the REX prefix, obviously, for extra registers (also remember `sil` and `dil` - a REX prefix with none of the bits set can still matter!)
- the REX prefix again, it used to be the short encoding (`40+rd`, `48+rd`) for `inc` and `dec`. So `inc` and `dec` must the `FF /1` encoding.
- `rip`-relative addressing
- 64bit load immediate and `mov` with a direct 64bit address
- sign-extend 32bit to 64bit (`movsxd`) shares opcode with `arpl`
- `les` and `lds` don't exist, reused as VEX prefixes (in 32bit mode, only `les` and `lds` with illegal operands are VEX prefixes, which is why the encoding of VEX prefixes is a bit odd)
- several old instructions that no one was using or are useless in 64bit mode were removed (decimal math, `bound`, `into`, `pushad`, `pop es` and friends)
- the `82 /?` aliases of `80 /?` are no longer valid
- `lahf` and `sahf` don't exist on some old x64 processors (not that you'd use them anyway..)

Comment: REX prefix is also needed for `cmpsq`, `lodsq`, `movsq`, `scasq` and `stosq`.